Typescript compile my string enum to a module
I defined a service package for my angular app, where it has string enum definitions:
export enum CloudTypeEnum {
   AZURE =  'AZURE',
   AMAZON = 'AMAZON',
   GOOGLE = 'GOOGLE',
}

In the tsconfig.json, I define the package path, where it exports the string enum:
"paths": {
            "@cloud-services/*": ["packages/service/*"],
}

When trying to use it in the angular service
import {CloudTypeEnum} from '@cloud-services';

isAzureCloud(type: CloudTypeEnum):boolean {
   return type == CloudTypeEnum.AZURE;
}

I found that the CloudTypeEnum is not a object but a module in the chrome inspector.
While the enum defined in the service is a object. So I am not sure why typescript compile my enum to module, which may lead if check always return false.


• Screenshots of text are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. • I can't easily reproduce this; certainly exports is some kind of "module", but CloudTypeEnum should be a property of that, not a module itself. Please consider [edit]ing to provide a [mre] we can easily use to see what you're seeing. Maybe even a web IDE link to an appropriately configured project? Or at least enough config info for interested parties to recreate.

You can use CodeSandbox to reproduce the issue and allows us to check out the problem.

The Chrome debugging tools are not resolving the value correctly. The value is correct, however, and should work properly.
Example
1. } else if (error.name === WorkOrderError.<redacted>) {
2.   switch (error.innerErrors[0]?.name) {

error.name on line 1 has the same value as WorkOrderError.<redacted>, but Chrome states the value of WorkOrderError.<redacted> is undefined and that WorkOrderError is a Module, as shown in the following screenshot.

The conditional on line 1 evaluates to true, though, and the code enters the conditional body on line 2. The JavaScript engine is using the correct value and executing appropriately.
